# How to append empty and its child in python?

Tags: python

Is there any way to append the child to the empty too ?

**Context:**

I have file1.blend that just contains an empty.
I have file2.blend that contains  an empty with some children.  (let's say cube, cube001)

I want to replace empty on file1.blend by the empty and it's child of the file2.blend

Based on some internet code, I made this. But it works only for mesh without any child

```
class replaceObjectEmptyBtn(bpy.types.Operator):
'''
The replaceObjectEmptyBtn is used to replace an object by keeping it's child
'''
bl_idname = 'mesh.replacebyobjectkeepempty'
bl_label = 'replace'
bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

def execute(self, context):

    # get the selection
    selection_names = [obj.name for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects]

    if not selection_names :
        self.report({'ERROR'}, "You must select the object that need to be replaced !")
    elif len(selection_names) > 1 :
        self.report({'ERROR'}, "You must select only 1 object !")
    else :
        # list to a string
        selectedObject = " ".join(selection_names)

        # path to the blend file
        # -- osx, linux
        #filepath = "/path/to/file.blend"
        # -- windows
        filepath = "D://Boris//Documents//test//toto.blend" 

        # when we append, set to true to keep the link to the original file
        link = False

        # link all objects named selection_names
        with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath, link=link) as (data_from, data_to):
            data_to.objects = [name for name in data_from.objects if name == selectedObject]
            
            # if the object specified doesn't exist
            if not data_to.objects:
                self.report({'ERROR'}, "Can't append because the other file don't have any object named: " + selectedObject)

        # append object to the current scene
        for obj in data_to.objects:
            if obj is not None:
                # delete the selected object to clean up the file
                bpy.ops.object.delete() 
                # add the new mesh
                bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj)
                # rename the new mesh and object
                obj.name = selectedObject

    return {"FINISHED"}
```

Comment: The best solution, according to comments on Blender bug reports, would be to create a collection in the source file, but the empty and its children in the collection and then link or append the collection to the destination file.  See [this bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T54187) for the discussion. "in Blender relation is from child to parent, so when importing a child, you'll import its parent too, but not the other way around. Best way to work around that is to put all relevant objects into a group, and then link that group instead."

Comment: Thank you @MartyFouts for these informations, I was abble to create a collection and append it instead of append an empty ! :)